# Rebooting from Ubuntu server - minimal desktop installation

Tags: unity, server, 12.10, reboot

I installed server 12.10 with the "--without-recommends ubuntu-desktop" option - this gives a minimal Unity GUI, without most of the addons for a desktop user.

But now I cannot figure out how to reboot. There is no system menu with these options; calling reboot from terminal prompt requires access to root.

Still very new to Ubuntu. How do I reboot from the GUI? control-atl-delete logs out, but does not reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if you can do it from the GUI, but from the Terminal, `sudo shutdown -r now` will do the trick.

If you want to power the machine off, `sudo shutdown -hP now` - the *h* is for halt, and the *P* is for Power off.

Comment: Opened terminal in Unity - typed it in - prompted for password and did reboot. Tnx.

Comment: BTW - how do you turn the machine OFF?

Answer (score 1):

When it prompts you for the root password, type your own password. As the person who installed it, you should automatically be in the sudo group.

I reboot with

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Jim answered first (I think) but +1.

Comment: BTW - how do you turn the machine OFF?

Comment: sudo shutdown -h now

Comment: correction: `sudo shutdown -hP now` - the **P** (yes, capitalized) tells the machine to actually turn the power off.  If you omit it, it halts but does not power off, which I have never really known ANYBODY, including myself, to want. :)